# How do I set $LESS invocation options in a lesskey file?

Tags: unix, keyboard-shortcuts, environment-variables, gnu, less

I'm trying to use `less`'s `lesskey`-file support, as described in [the manpage](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?less):

```
KEY BINDINGS

   You  may define your own less commands by using the program lesskey (1)
   to create a lesskey file.  This file specifies a set  of  command  keys
   and  an  action  associated with each key.  You may also use lesskey to
   change the line-editing keys (see LINE EDITING), and to set environment
   variables. …
```

Unfortunately, this isn't working for me:

```
$ mkdir test_lesskey && cd !#:1
$ less --version
less 471 (PCRE regular expressions)
Copyright (C) 1984-2014  Mark Nudelman
$ cat <<-EOF >a_lesskey   
   #env
   LESS=-?
EOF
$ lesskey -o a_dot_less 'a_lesskey'
$ less -FX a_dot_less
^@M+Gc^@^@e^@^@v        ^@LESS^@84-?^@xEnd
$ less --lesskey-file=a_dot_less "~/.profile"
```

At this point, `less` is opened normally, instead of printing the `less -?` usage-text and quitting as expected.

I've experimented with a couple different flags (and formattings), and none of them seem to work as described in the manpage.

The lesskey mechanism *overall* definitely works; I can define, say, the following:

```
#command
e     quit
```

… and `less` will exit, as expected, if I hit the <kbd>e</kbd> key. It's *only* the environment-variable section that I cannot make work as-expected.

I've tried this on both Arch (`pacman -S less`) and OS X (`brew install less`; it's irrelevant on an out-of-the-box OS X, as the OS X `less` is patched not to include `lesskey` support.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use `less` 458 on OS X 10.8.5 and could reproduce your problem.

`-k filename` or `--lesskey-file=filename` don't seem to work with the `#env` section.

I suggest you use the default paths or variables and file a bug at the [developer's website](http://www.greenwoodsoftware.com/less/bugs.html) where a problem related also to this option and section was already reported and fixed, see reference 141.

Comment: I e-mailed the developer, with a link to this thread. We'll see if he has a solution for me! (=

Comment: For now, I simply did as you suggest: Moved the actual *keys* in the lesskey into `~/.less`, compiled them to `~/.lesskey`, and then [moved all the environment-configuration into my `~/.profile`](https://github.com/ELLIOTTCABLE/System/commit/6ae9061bc9c6616c0286e31a1935dff39853d55f) with a caveat that I'm only doing so because it's broken.

Comment: I already mailed him last month and was told, he'll look into it — I don't see it in the [list of known bugs](http://www.greenwoodsoftware.com/less/bugs.html) though.  
Also, I think you're using the defaults the other way around. `lesskey` will take `~/.lesskey` and output `~/.less`. You can also use `LESSKEY` or `LESSKEY_SYSTEM` vars. I suggest you check the `man` page for further details.